# creating a pdf file through java with a hyperlink

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a PDF file using Java. What I have seen is that I must have the iText library so I went and I got it.

This is the piece of code I wrote but it's all full of errors... There is something going wrong here.

```
//com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter

public class document  {
    Document document = new Document (PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, \
    new FileOutputStream("C:\ITextTest.pdf"));
    document.open(); 

    document.add(new Paragraph("First page of the document."));
    //document.add(new Paragraph("Some more text on the \ first page with different color and font type.", 
    //FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD, new Color(255, 150, 200))));

    document.close(); 
}
```

Comment: There's a lot going wrong here. I'd worry about the syntax before the PDFWriter.

Comment: I tried doing exactly as what they did in the tutorial

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-javapdf/

Comment: I'll bet that IBM did not have `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, \ ` in the manual, since that would not compile.

Comment: @AndrewThompson can u check the manual !

Comment: I can, yes.  But I detest PDFs, so I won't.  If the manual truly does have stray characters like that floating around, put it back where you got it and look for other instructions (or another API).

Comment: Please don't use a field called `document` in a class called `document`. Actually, please don't call your class `document` but instead learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them. Also, you need to put your code in a method! (And yes, the tutorial does use \ when lines are wrapped...)

Comment: This documentation from IBM (apart from having its examples wrongly formatted) refers to a mighty old version of iText. You might want to refer to the actual iText official documentation, and use the latest iText build available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MyPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        try {

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "Test.pdf")));
            document.open();
            String content = "pdf data...";
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(content);
            document.add(paragraph);

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            document.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the rest,but this for sure is a mistake. Please rectify this :

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\ITextTest.pdf"));
```

1. There was an unnecessary `\` in there.
2. You need to escape `\` in the file path. So add an extra `\`.